# jQuery Sortable, save changed order of list items into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to save NOT the id's (actually I have no id's in my li-tags) but the values of the list in a database.

I think I need the methods serialize or toArray. I would prefer toArray because I don't really need to send my data to an other location via ajax etc.

It would be perfect to get an array of the list item values like this:

```
array array( 
  [0] = "value-1", 
  [1] = "value-2", 
  [2] = "value-3" 
)
```

How can I reach that?

```js
$(function() { 
 $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
  update: function( event, ui ) {
          //don't know how to continue correctly
  }
 }).disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<ul id="sortable">
   <li>value-1</li>
   <li>value-2</li>
   <li>value-3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick

Edit (thanks to Matti Virkkunen)

```
var somearray;

$("#sortable li").each(function(index){
    somearray.push($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Somebody has been using too much PHP. You need `.push()`. Also I'd prefer `.text()` here.